# NSMutableArray empties after tableView editing turned on

Tags: nsmutablearray, tableview

Very simple situation... very strange problem.

I have a retained iVar NSMutableArray that I load a few objects in on viewDidLoad.
That array is used to populate a tableView.
Everything is fine... until

I turn editing on for the tableView.
Suddenly the array is empty!

Ideas?

Comment: Are you by any chance turning on editing in the `viewDidLoad` as well? I just noticed that my entire tableView appears empty when I do that and I haven't figured out yet why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to initialize the NSMutableArray in the init method. That's the most common problem that I've noticed- adding objects to an array that hasn't been created doesn't let you access the objects later.

Comment: Am doing that also in the viewDidLoad. I've tried every possible variation on 'retain,' 'autoRelease,' etc. thinking in was the array's problem. Now I believe it has to do with the tableView somehow corrupting the array on reload.

Comment: How are you initializing the array? Also, it may be an issue with when you initialize the array and the tableview- the tableview may try to load before the array has been created.

Comment: Still trying to figure this one out. Will post a solution when I have a better idea.